# Converting Byte[] to drawing the waves in a picturebox (overflow error)

Tags: c#, drawing, system.drawing

ive currently got a live voice call application using UDP and im trying to get the incoming voice to be plotted like a wave form in a picturebox. I looked at 2 open source ways for doing this and both bring back the overflow error when i try to draw a line. My code is below:

Incoming Voice via UDP:

```
                while (LISTENING)
            {
                byte[] b = UDP_LISTENER.Receive(ref endPoint); //incoming audio bytes
                byte[] decoded = listenerThreadState.Codec.Decode(b, 0, b.Length);
                WAVE_PLAYER.AddSamples(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);//plays it out the speakers

                float[] x = FloatArrayFromByteArray(decoded);//converts to a float array

                DrawNormalizedAudios(ref x, PBWaveForm, Color.Red);//plots the wave form
            }
```

Function to produce the waveform:

```
        public static void DrawNormalizedAudios(ref float[] data, PictureBox pb,
Color color)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        if (pb.Image == null)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            bmp = (Bitmap)pb.Image;
        }

        int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
        int width = bmp.Width - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);
        int height = bmp.Height - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            Pen pen = new Pen(color);
            int size = data.Length;
            for (int iPixel = 0; iPixel < width; iPixel++)
            {
                // determine start and end points within WAV
                int start = (int)((float)iPixel * ((float)size / (float)width));
                int end = (int)((float)(iPixel + 1) * ((float)size / (float)width));
                float min = float.MaxValue;
                float max = float.MinValue;
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
                {
                    float val = data[i];
                    min = val < min ? val : min;
                    max = val > max ? val : max;
                }
                int yMax = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((max + 1) * .5 * height);
                int yMin = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((min + 1) * .5 * height);
                g.DrawLine(pen, iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMax,
                    iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMin);
            }
        }
        pb.Image = bmp;
    }
```

Now there was 2 funcitons but both of them gave the same error which was this exacly: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Overflow error."

So its gotta be a problem with the bytes of audio right? i tried putting the byte[] b instead of decoded but that didnt make it far and i dont think thats the problem. The audio being sent is sending every 50ms, so is it a fact that it just cant keep up? theres apps for drawing which keep up with more than 50ms so that cant be it. When i googled the error it said something to do with the boundarys but i didnt really understand it, any help is appriciated

Comment: How  can you tell when you receive the entire image?  You will get an error if you try to process data before and entire image is received.  To make sure you get the entire binary file you should add a header to the image containing the byte count of binary data.  Then wait until entire message is received before processing by counting number of bytes.

Comment: thanks for your reply, im abit of a beginner but what your saying is its trying to draw the waveform before the byte[] has been fully received?

Comment: Yes!  you can verify by checking byte count in receive against sent byte count.

Comment: hmm im not entirly sure how to do that but i did a console.writline(decoded.lengh) and it gave me 640 before it entered the function to draw the waves, so surly that would still work? even if it didnt finish receiving all of it, it should of plot 640 bytes worth?

Comment: Images are never that small.  They are usually over 10,000 bytes.  Graphics.FromImage(bmp) will give an exception if the bmp is not valid which will occur when you do not have the entire image.

Comment: You data is in bytes, but the pixel data is I think is 16 bits (2 bytes).  An overflow exception will occur if you are exceeding the size of an array.   This can occur if your division of size/width is wrong.  Your 'end' will be too small creating an array that is too small.

Comment: thanks i think it normally works because it uses a song which is massive but mine is just very small bits of audio 20 times a second so it wont be big enough, im gonna have to find another way, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Do you know anything about the audio format you are listeing to? And do you know which line throws the error and what the number at that moment are?